# Biholomorphism between 2 non simply connected domains

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Is the annulus of centre $0$ and radii $1$ and $2$ biholomorphic to the punctured disc $$\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ 0<|z| <1\}$$ ? Why ?

I know the Riemann mapping theorem but here we have  non simply connected domains.

Comment: And also [of this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/248985/123116).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. The more general result is:

> For $0\le r<R<\infty$ and $0\le r^\prime<R^\prime<\infty$,
>   the annuli $$\{ z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,r<z<R \}$$ and 
>   $$\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,r^\prime<z<R^\prime\}$$
>   are biholomorphically equivalent if and only if
>   $$R r^\prime=r R^\prime$$

You will find the proof probably in any beginner's text book on complex analysis.

You can read up the proof of the general statement for example [here](http://cykenleung.blogspot.com/2012/04/conformal-equivalence-of-annuli.html).

Your special case is easier since $r=0$. See [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248985/a-question-on-analytic-function) given in the comment above

*Note:* 
In $\mathbb{C}$, biholomorphic equivalence is the same as conformal equivalence.

Comment: @WLOG: It is often given as an exercise, possibly with a few hints in a complex analysis course. At least that's where I know it from.

Comment: but in your lemma $r \neq 0  $, in my problem $r =0$

Comment: @WLOG: No, I wrote $r\ge 0$.